# Maximizing log-likelihood: Determinining whether critical points are maximums

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

Consider the following proof of the fact that $\bar{X}$, the sample mean, is the MLE of parameter $\lambda$ in a Poisson distribution.

> Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be the observations of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ with $X_i \sim
> \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$. Then we want to solve
> \begin{align*}
>     \text{argmax}_{\lambda} \mathcal{L}(\lambda \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n)
> \end{align*}
> Observe that
> \begin{align*}
>     P(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid \lambda) &= \prod_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{\lambda^{x_i}
>     e^{-\lambda}}{x_i!}
> \end{align*}
> To maximize this with respect to $\lambda$, we observe that
> \begin{align*}
>     \frac{d}{d\lambda} \ln \left[  \prod_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{\lambda^x_i
>     e^{-\lambda}}{x_i!}\right] &= \frac{d}{d\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\ln
> \frac{\lambda^{x_i}e^{-\lambda}}{x_i !}\right) \\ 
> &= \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - n
> \end{align*}
> Then, if we let $S := \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$,
> \begin{align*}
>     \frac{S}{\lambda} - n &= 0 \iff \lambda = \frac{S}{n}
> \end{align*}
> where obviously $S/n = \bar{X}$.

My question regards the claim that setting the derivative to zero finds the maximizing $\lambda$. That the log-likelihood has a critical point at $\lambda = \bar{X}$ is proven; however, what guarantees that this critical point is not a minimum?

I am aware that the second derivative test answers this question, because it is negative at $\lambda = \bar{X}$. But the book this comes from is entirely on probability theory and I presume that it's using some fact about the Poisson distribution to implicitly conclude that the point is a maximum. In short, can one conclude that $\lambda = S/n$ is a maximizing point instead of a minimizing point from the nature of the distribution at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pmf of Poisson distribution is **log-concave** in $\color{blue} {\lambda}$. This implies that the log of the likelihood function, given by
$$
 \ln \left[  \prod_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{\lambda^{x_i}
    e^{-\lambda}}{x_i!}\right]= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\ln
\frac{\lambda^{x_i}e^{-\lambda}}{x_i !}\right) =\left  (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \right )\color{blue} {\ln \lambda} - n\color{blue} {\lambda}-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln (x_i !)$$

is **concave** in $\color{blue} {\lambda}$. Thus, the point that makes its derivative zero is the global optimum.

Comment: This answers my question. Much appreciated!

Comment: @lafinur you are very welcome!